# multitail/ssh leaves processes hanging around after exit

Tags: ssh, tail

I'm using multitail via SSH to filter log output on a number of servers like so:

```
multitail -L "ssh foo.bar.com tail -n 0 -q -F /var/log/out.log | grep match"
```

This works great, however when multitail exits multiple processes are left hanging around -- three to be exact: bash, tail, and grep.

How can I force multitail (or more likely ssh) to terminate child processes and exit?

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the -t option with ssh. See the following link:

https://superuser.com/questions/20679/why-does-my-remote-process-still-run-after-killing-an-ssh-session